# Worker nodes out of space due to spark streaming application executors have jar files

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-standalone

My spark streaming application is running in standalone mode, executors which have finished are still holding jar files.

After a couple of days, it starts failing because worker Nodes are going out of space.
How can we delete these completed executors?

Comment: i think  onBatchCompleted is missing in code  where it need to release resource

Comment: You can enable cleanup and reduce cleanup interval. but I think your issue should be due to log files.

Answer (score 0):

add below property in spark-env.sh

```
export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=300 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=60"
```